# Assigning values for variables inside if conditional - Allways bad practice?

Tags: c, conditional-statements

Is always a bad practice of programming assign a value for a variable inside the if conditional space? Check this example, if it is not clear what I mean by that:

```
int c;
//code...
if ( foo1() == 1 || ( (c = foo2()) == -1)) //true if foo1 == 1 or foo2 == -1
    //more code...
```

The way I was instructed is to place the `c = foo2()` outside if. However, imagine if `foo2()` was a expensive function. Is this attribution of the variable *c* a bad programming habit, even in this case?

Comment: If it’s expensive and you’re trying to short-circuit you can use a nested-if. IMO it’s now always bad, but it can lead to developer error and/or misunderstanding if the code reader isn’t being careful enough.

Comment: I suspect this will be closed as "primarily opinion based", since everyone has their own opinion on code style.  It's a trade-off; having encountered this pattern before I like that I can take in at a glance what is going on; if we "rewrite the line properly" it's going to need an intermediate variable and several lines of code, which might take longer to digest.  On the other hand, someone who's never seen this might be puzzled by what's going on.

Comment: Having said that - in the "more code" part, `c` will be uninitialized in the case of `foo1() == 1`, so we may well be looking at "spaghetti code" that is easy to introduce a bug for if someone makes changes to the "more code", overlooking that it was careful to not read the value of `c` in the `foo1() == 1` case.

Comment: @Homunculus Yeah, what usually happens is that a bunch of people post talking about what code style they prefer;  sometimes there is some value in that, but the site moderators have deemed that it turns into an unhelpful jumble of thoughts more often than not.

Comment: Not sure if agree with M.M. It's a very specific question, and it did not solicit opinion. Also note that everyone is basically giving the same answer. This seems like valuable knowledge to me.

Comment: The usual idiom for reading characters from stdin is `int c; while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) { /* process character c */ }` It would be more awkward to write of the assignment had to be moved out of the condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Always and Never rarely have a place when it comes to coding practices. Part of our job as professional developers is to maintain an appropriate balance between function, efficiency, and ease of maintenance.

I definitely agree that what you’re describing is something I would throw into the “strongly avoid” category because it certainly makes the code more difficult to comprehend and as a result introduces higher risk of bugs sneaking in during maintenance.

Answer (score 1):

If you really do not want to do like that, you can write like that:

```
int c;
//code...
c =  foo1();

if ( c != 1)
{
    c = foo2();
}

if(c == 1 || c == -1){...
    //more code...
```

Comment: That’s... an approach. Seems needlessly difficult to reason about.

Comment: This isn't the same logic as the original code

Comment: @M.M Why do you think so? Only if it is necessary to use "c" variable in the future?

Comment: If `foo1()` returns `0` and `foo2()` returns `-1`, this code sets `c` to `1`, whereas the original code set `c` to `-1`.  (The value of `c` presumably goes on to be used inside the body, otherwise there was no reason to save it in the first place)

Comment: Yes, u'r right. Is that ok now?

Comment: It's not clear from the OP whether the `//code...` at the start might set the value of `c`; if it does, then the OP code leaves the pre-set value of `c` intact in the case `foo1() == 1`, whereas your code overwrites `c`.  Now, maybe this is a good thing in terms of reading the code and trying to understand the value of `c`; I'm saying that OP may need to carefully evaluate the entire function when making the change you suggest.

Comment: Yes, thank you, you see really subtlety of the task. It is very cool. If so, well, maybe i have to declare one more variable, to check foo1()?

Answer (score 1):

Good Practice is writing coherent, readable and efficient code. While some "rules" can be pretty black and white, others are more flexible. I believe that if you can achieve coherent, readable and efficient, you're doing well. I would generally not do this, but I most definitely have when it made the most sense in the given context.

Answer (score 1):

I would leave you to decide whether it is good or bad, but here are some considerations.

1. Assignment operator and equality comparison operator look too similar. Even if the context is unambiguous, it still requires more mental effort to read.
2. Tools like compilers and static analyzers may not understand your intention and still issue warnings.
3. Assignments in short circuit evaluation may not be understood by everyone.
4. There are alternatives. Assignments can be put outside `if` condition.

And here is an alternative.

The condition can still be put outside the `if` statement and store in a boolean variable. And the short circuit evaluation can still be used.

```
bool condition = foo1() == 1 || ( (c = foo2()) == -1);

if (condition)
    op();
```

C++17 introduces `if` statement with initialization.

```
if (bool condition = foo1() == 1 || ( (c = foo2()) == -1); condition)
    op();
```

Comment: Your suggested alternative does not "fix" the issues you raise in points 1,2,3

Comment: @M.M Because it is not a "fix" for points 1,2,3. It is an example for point 4, to show alternatives exist.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is,  what is the benefit of making the change you suggested?  It's equally (un)readable as the original, and the creation of `condition` seems redundant if its value is not used later on. (Presumably the value `c` is the one that is used later on)

Comment: @M.M There is really no huge benefit IMO, except for trying to stick to some coding rules, may be set by a teacher or manager. That's why I leave the OP and readers to decide, as stated in the first sentence.